# Is the $c$-transform $f^c$ defined by $f^c(y) := \inf_{x\in X} [c(x, y)- f(x)]$ measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions, optimal-transport, polish-spaces

Let $X, Y$ be Polish spaces and $c:X \times Y \to [0, +\infty)$ lower semi-continuous. Assume that $f:X \to \mathbb R \cup\{\pm\infty\}$ is measurable. We define the $c$-transform $f^c:Y \to \mathbb R \cup\{\pm\infty\}$ of $f$ by
$$
f^c(y) := \inf_{x\in X} [c(x, y)- f(x)] \quad \forall y \in Y.
$$
This $c$-transform is fundamental in optimal transport.

> Can we prove that $f^c$ is measurable?

Comment: I think the answer is yes. Because $X$ is Polish it contains a countable dense subset  $\{x_1,x_2,...\}$. It should be true that

$$
\{f^c<a\}=\bigcup_{n}\{c(x_n,.)-f(x_n)<a\}
$$
which shows that $f^c$ is measurable.

Comment: @KurtG. But $c,f$ are not assume to be continuous.

Comment: I know. Because $c$ is *lower semi-continuous* it should be true that for every $n$ and every $b$ the set $\{c(x_n,.)-f(x_n)\le b\}$ is closed, hence Borel measurable. ***Next Hint***: $\{c(x_n,.)-f(x_n)<a\}=\bigcup_m\{c(x_n,.)-f(x_n)\le a-\frac{1}{m}\}$. Seeing your MSE profile I am assuming that you should be able to check my reasonging and/or work out all details.

Comment: @KurtG. We have $f^c (y) < a \iff \exists x \in X, c(x, y)- f(x) < a$, so $\{f^c < a\} = \bigcup_{x \in X} \{ c(x, \cdot)- f(x) < a\}$. Could you explain how to get $\{f^c < a\} = \bigcup_n \{ c(x_n, \cdot)- f(x_n) < a\}$?

Comment: Yes. I see a gap here. When $c$ and $f$ were continuous no problem but they are not.